# Corona SDK pathToFile issue

Tags: coronasdk

In my app I have a structure similar to the following:

```
app (baseDirectory)
 |
 +-> config
      |
      +-> Levels
```

When using corona I am trying to autoload all files in the Levels directory. Below is how I am currently doing it. *Note: This **does** work on Windows just not mac.*

```
local dirPath = system.pathForFile('config/Levels')
for file in lfs.dir(dirPath) do
    if (file ~= '.' and file ~= '..') then
        -- require the file
    end
end
```

Now if I use the following it works on Mac but not the 'config/Levels'.

```
local dirPath = system.pathForFile('config')
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong. I would assume since it works on Windows but not on Mac that it would be a bug.

---

So in conclusion how can I get the following to work with the above directory structure

```
local dirPath = system.pathForFile('config/Levels')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much debugging I have figured out the solution for Mac. Below is my function for getting files in a directory. Works for both Windows and Mac.

**Must have a file named main.lua in the baseDirectory.**

```
-- path is relative to the baseDirectory
function getFiles(path)
    local filenames = { }
    local baseDir = system.pathForFile('main.lua'):gsub("main.lua", "")
    for file in lfs.dir(baseDir .. path) do
        if (file ~= '.' and file ~= '..') then
            table.insert(filenames, file)
        end
    end
    if (#filenames == 0) then return false end
    return filenames
end
```

The problem is system.pathForFile('directory/subdirectory') does not work on Mac as it is strictly looking for a file. As long as it can find some file in the baseDirectory you can append on the relative path to retrieve all files in the intended directory.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to change "Levels" in "levels".
Maybe it is case sensitive. 
Second solution is to not use "levels" directory inside **config** folder.
Here is how I suggest to organize your files:

```
 app (baseDirectory)  
 |  
 +-> • configLevels  
     • configPlayer  
     • configOther
```

Comment: I've tested and capitalized directories are not a problem. I personally don't like that structure because its redundant. Why have three folders in the baseDirectory prefixed with __config__ when you can have a single config folder with sub folders? It seems more semantic.